# How to return data in custom json format?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, jsonserializer

**Models**

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    transaction_type = models.ForeignKey(
        TransactionType,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

class Transfer(models.Model):
    transaction_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Transaction,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    debit = models.ForeignKey(
        Account,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='debit'
    )
```

**Serializers** for getting json

```
class TransferSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Transfer
        fields = ('created_at', 'debit',)

class TransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    transfers = TransferSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = ('created_at', 'transaction_type', 'transfers')
```

**Views**

```
class TransactionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Transaction.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TransactionSerializer
    pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination
```

How to return data with following json format?
What is the best approach? 
When i try to run it i getting error "Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `transfers` on serializer `TransactionSerializer`."

```
{
  "created_at": "2019-08-18",
  "transaction_type_id": "1",
  "transfers": {"debit": "100"},
}
```

Comment: [Nested relationships](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In your `Transfer` model, in the transaction ForeignKey, add `related_name=transfers`.
- In your `TransactionSerializer`, add the class attribute:

```py
transfers = TransferSerializer(many=True)
```

- EDIT: In your `TransferSerializer`, modify `fields` for `fields=('created_at','transaction_type_id', 'transfers')`
  This will give you:

```
{
  "created_at": "2019-08-18",
  "transaction_type_id": "1",
  "transfers": [
    {"transfer_type": 1, "debit": "100", ...},
    ...
  ],
}
```

Comment: I getting error ```Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `transfers` on serializer `TransactionSerializer`.```

Comment: Try specifying the `TransactionSerializer` meta `fields` with `fields=('created_at','transaction_type_id', 'transfers')`

Comment: got same error ```Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `transfers` on serializer `TransactionSerializer```

Comment: Can you update the models and serializers in your original post?

Comment: Please add the `related_name='transfers'` in the transaction foreign key that is in your transfer model

Comment: How i can validate custom params in (GET, POST) requests?

Comment: Please read [how to deserialize data thanks to serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation) and ask your question afterwards if the documentation didn't answer your questions